# Worcloud by File input in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, word-cloud

I try to create wordcloud, but it show "Reading from shinyoutput object is not allowed.

This is code for server.

`server.r`

```
function(input, output, session) {
  mydata <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$finput
    if(is.null(inFile)){return()}
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ',',quote = "")
  })



  word = reactive({
    myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(output$fData))
    myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
    myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
    myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
    myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus)
    v = sort(slam::row_sums(myDTM),decreasing = TRUE)
    data.frame(word=names(v),freq=v)
  })  

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    wordcloud(words = word()$word,
              freq = word()$freq, 
              random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.3,   
              scale=c(4,.5),max.words=15, 
              colors=brewer.pal(8,"Dark2"))
  })
}
```

This is code for UI

```
UI.r
```

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),

  navbarPage("Sentimen Analisis Tokopedia",
             tabPanel("Sentiment Analysis",

                      fluidRow(
                        column(8,
                               fileInput("finput",label = h3("Upload File CSV"))),

                        column(4,
                               dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range"))
                        )),

                      tabsetPanel(type = "tab", 
                                  tabPanel("Data", 
                                           br(),
                                           DT::dataTableOutput("fData")),

                                  tabPanel("WordCloud", 
                                           br(),
                                           plotOutput("plot")
                                  )
             )
)
)
)             
)
```

I think there is something wrong with `myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(output$fData))` I tried to replace it but it was still an error. Please help me

Comment: hi, can you add the ```ui``` part so that your code is fully reproducible?

Comment: Edited, please check.

Comment: you ```ui``` does not work, please correct it

Comment: I think you might want `myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(mydata()))` where `mydata()` includes the data from the loaded file? In addition, you can add `output$fData <- DT::renderDataTable({mydata()})` to your server function so that your data table will be updated with the loaded data too?